# T-SQL query to get the last value in a list of months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the data I have

```
date            value
30/03/2014  625949
23/03/2014  624549
16/03/2014  623149
09/03/2014  621549
02/03/2014  619749
23/02/2014  617749
16/02/2014  616149
09/02/2014  614549
02/02/2014  612949
19/01/2014  609749
12/01/2014  608149
06/01/2014  606749
```

if I want to get only the last value in a month, for example output like below, how I can get it?

```
date            value
30/03/2014  625949
23/02/2014  617749
19/01/2014  609749
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date,value FROM table1 WHERE date in (
    SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1 GROUP BY MONTH(date)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
;with Cte as(Select tDate,value, C=ROW_NUMBER()
         over(PARTITION by convert(varchar(6), tdate, 112) order by tdate desc)
         From #Temp )

Select *
from cte
where C=1
```

Fiddle [Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3b43/1)

Comment: you should replace `month(tdate)` with `convert(varchar(6), tdate, 112)`

Comment: @huMptyduMpty You should use @snyder comment or `PARTITON BY YEAR(tdate), MONTH(tdate)`. That is for case of one month in different years.

Comment: @snyder: Updated, didn't got it on the first place :)